# Classical measurement error model in R

Tags: r, meta-analysis

I'm not sure if this is precisely a measurement error model or not.  I'm working on performing meta analysis, and the model I'm starting with is fairly basic.

\begin{aligned}
X_i &= \mu_i + e_i \\
Y_i &= \beta \mu_i + g_i + \delta_i
\end{aligned}

The random components are $e_i$, $g_i$, and $\delta_i$,and the variance is known for $e_i$ and $\delta_i$.  This falls under a measurement error model with measurement in both the predictor and response.  How would I fit this model in R?

Comment: Are $e_i$ and $\delta_i$ (assumed to be) independent? Also, what are the distributional assumptions? In particular, are $e_i$, $\delta_i$, and $g_i$ assumed to be normally distributed? Finally, did you really mean $\beta \mu_i$ and not $\beta + \mu_i$?

Comment: They could be correlated, but literature indicates that this is a minor concern. All errors are assumed normal, and the variance is **known** for $e_i$ and $\delta_i$

Comment: yes $\beta \mu_i$, indicating the relationship between $X_i$ and $Y_i$.

Comment: The 'simex' package is popular for measurement error models....

Comment: @Andrew Redd: have never searched for such models but Rseek also finds `gbev` package (or `MeasurementError.cor` for a simple model) as one that may be interesting. Do you have some known methods or do you know how it is implemented in other programs like S-Plus, Stata, SPSS or whenever?

Comment: from this model, $g_i$ and $\delta_i$ are not identifiable.  For $g_i + \delta_i=(g_i+c) + (\delta_i-c)$ and the adjustment leaves the variances unchanged.  This model would be identifiable if $g_i=g$ (i.e. same for all i) or if it was the same across clusters (as in multilevel models).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $\sigma^{2} = {\rm var}(\epsilon)$ is known then you can use the SIMEX method (Stefanski and Cook, 1995) to extrapolate backwards to determine the model the effect when $X$ is not measured with error. The basic idea is -

1. Generate a grid of $\sigma_{1}, ..., \sigma_{k}$ obtained by adding progressively more measurement error to $X$
2. Fit $Y_{i} = \beta X_{i} + \varepsilon_{i}$ and for each $\sigma$ and 
   obtain the corresponding $\beta_{1}, ..., \beta_{k}$.
3. Fit a regression of $\beta_{1}, ..., \beta_{k}$ vs. $\sigma_{1}, ..., \sigma_{k}$ and extrapolate backward to predict $\beta$ when $\sigma = 0$.

This is a rather crude description of the method, but this is the basic approach. Cook and Stefanski show that, under some conditions, this will work. Have a look at the paper.